# How do I keep the drop down value selected when I update the record/form data in PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Here is the code that i am using for drop down to select.

```
<select name="formreg" value="">
    <option value="Registered" <?php if($f_reg == 'Registered') { ?> selected <?php echo $f_reg; } ?> >Registered</option>
    <option value="NonReg" <?php if($f_reg == 'NonReg') { ?> selected <?php echo $f_reg; } ?> >NonReg</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select name="formreg" value="">

<option value="Registered" <?php if($f_reg == 'Registered') { ?> selected <?php echo $f_reg; }  ?> >Registered</option>
<option value="NonReg" <?php if($f_reg == 'NonReg') { ?> selected <?php echo $f_reg; }  ?> >NonReg</option>

</select>

Comment: Please post your code as part of your question, instead of in a comment. Give  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a visit for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="regform">
    <option value="Registered" <?php if (isset($register) && $register=='Registered') {?> selected='selected' <?php echo $register; }?>>Registered</option>
    <option value="NonReg" <?php if (isset($nonreg) && $nonreg == 'NonReg') {?> selected='selected' <?php echo $nonreg;} ?>>NonReg</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of script:

```
  $f_reg = $_POST["f_reg"]; // or $f_reg = $_GET["f_reg"] if you pass parameters as the url part
```

then your < select > tag:

```
<select name="formreg">
  <option value="Registered" <?php if ($f_reg == "Registered") print "selected"?>>Registered</option>
  <option value="NonReg" <?php if ($f_reg == "NonReg") print "selected"?>>NonReg</option>
</select>
```